# Weird noise on css hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I figured I would ask you all before emailing the developer. Is anyone familiar with a strange 'noise' accross the screen on a CSS hover? This only happens when I use a variable instead of a number in the cssMap function as seen below. I am using [Winston Wolf's CSS Clickable Map](http://winstonwolf.pl/clickable-maps). See in action here: http://animalnecessity.com/company/where-to-buy

```
var windowWidth=J(window).width();
            console.log(windowWidth);

            if (windowWidth>500 && windowWidth<750){
                var size= 750;
            }
            else if (windowWidth>750 && windowWidth<960){
                var size= 850;
            }
            else if (windowWidth>960){
                var size= 960;
            }
            else
                console.log('Not working');


            J(function(J)   
            {       
                J('#map-usa').cssMap(       
            {           
                'size' : size,          
                'tooltips' : 'floating',            
                'cities': false,                    
            });     
            });
```

Comment: Take a screenshot. I'm not seeing anything when I hover over it.

Comment: I am seeing a distortion on the map covering most of South America, half of Africa and all of Australia. (using chrome). Also get distortions when hovering over some places across the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your continents image seems to be corrupted: http://animalnecessity.com/skin/frontend/default/animalnecessity/cssmap-continents/continents-960.png

[image: Continents]

And here it is in Chrome:
[image]

Comment: Your right! I just replaced with fresh images and its all good!